# Print data from REST to Div React JS

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am trying to make an facebook style like application where the app gets to Load from a REST api and prints the data on html like feeds.
I am starting out something like this , i got a bit confused along the line. So i wanted some form of clarity.
My code is looking like this

```
import './Home.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const MyDashBoard = () =>{

    let userId = localStorage.getItem('userinfo');

    useEffect(() =>{
        fetch('https://instagramklone-restapi.herokuapp.com/api/posts/'+userId,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then((response)=> response.json())
        .then((responseJson) =>{
            let mainUser = responseJson.username;
            let imgUploaded = responseJson.imgUrl;
            let mPost = responseJson.post;
        })
    },[])

    return (
        <div align="center">
                <table className="headerTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table border="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                <td width="270px">
                                <p align="right"/></td>
                                <td width="108px">
                                <p align="right"/>
                                <img border="0" src="images/735145cfe0a4.png" width="103px" height="29px"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="150px">
                                <p align="center"/>
                                <input type="image" src="images/home.png" width="27" height="25" align="right" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="135">
                                    <p align="center"/>
                                    <input type="image" src="images/logout.png" width="27" height="25" align="left" />
                                </td>
                                <td width="128"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <div className="uploadImagesDiv">
                    <table className="postsTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="76">
                                <p align="left"/>
                                <textarea rows="4" name="S1" cols="73" className="textArea" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="34">
                                <p align="left"/>
                                <input type="file" name="file1" size="73" className="fileUploaderClass"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td height="34">
                               <p align="left"/>
                               <input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" className="postButton" />
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div className="postsDiv">
                    <table border="0" width="42%" height="600" className="feedsTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="3">
                                <p align="left"/>&nbsp; <b>username</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="428">
                            <p align="center"/>
                            <img border="0" src="images/1wwdyw5de8avrdkgtz5n.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" className="photoMain" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                               <p align="left" />&nbsp; <b>comment</b>
                            </td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p align="left"/>&nbsp;
                </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyDashBoard;
```

Its supposed to print the data on this div `<feedstable>` But i dont know how to go about it, Please i need help.

Answer (score 0):

The response is out of reach as is, because it only lives within the effect.

If you create state for it, you can just set that.

```
const [myData, setMyData] = useState();
```

Then inside the effect:

```
 .then(response => setMyData(response))
```

You can then reference it by using {myData.someProperty}
Be advised that myData will be undefined until you resolve the Promise in the useEffect. So you need to check if for undefined first (or introduce a second state-variable "loading" that can be set and checked against to see if the component is ready to display the content.